# Try loop inside for loop date parsing Python

Tags: python, date, try-except

so I have this list of items

```
Cool beans 12/13/2016  12:00:00 AM
12/15/2016 0:00
10/28/2016 0:00
11/22/2006 0:00
3/31/2017 0:00
1/23/2017 0:00
9/2/2016 0:00
8/18/2016 0:00
2/23/2017 0:00
8/3/2016 0:00
5/11/2010 0:00
10/11/2016 0:00
4/25/2017 0:00
8/29/2016 0:00
5/31/2017 0:00
4/14/2017 0:00
4/6/2016 0:00
12/11/2014 0:00
1/31/2017 0:00
10/12/2010 0:00
```

Im using the following function to parse the dates

```
def try_parsing_date(text):
    for fmt in ('%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', '%Y/%m/%d', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'):
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(text, fmt).strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
        except ValueError:
            pass
    raise ValueError('no valid date format)
```

On top of raising the value error is there a way where I can just either change the text to some other date or just make the function continue? In the first entry of my list I added the words cool beans and I know that will raise a value error, but instead of stopping the code, I want nothing to be returned or I want the code to pass over this value or I want to change the value and then rerun the function, any of these solutions will suffice but I dont know how to do it.

Comment: Then why `raise` an exception at all?

Comment: If you remove the `raise` it will... just work!

Comment: On further reading, your question is unclear to me. Only a successful `try` will break out of your function, or you deliberately raise an exception once you've exhausted all of your format options. You could change `raise ValueError('no valid date format)` to `return '1900/01/01'` or just remove it (which will automatically `return None`). I'm not clear on what you want to do.

Comment: That makes sense @roganjosh, but what if I want to function to skip that value all together, is that possible?

Comment: At a guess, `return text`? That will just return back to you whatever the input was, unchanged.

Comment: That is, again, in place of `raise ValueError('no valid date format)`.

Comment: Would I have to change except ValueError to just Except too?

Comment: No no. So let me clarify what you want. You want to try parsing a datetime string and return a date string. If you can't find a valid datetime format to parse the initial string, you want to return that string unchanged. So `'cool beans'` would still be in the final result? Is that correct?

Comment: Or you can have a default date string returned, you left a lot of options open. But am I on the right lines?

Comment: Yeah exactly that last point, I want a default date string to be returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your current approach is that, once you've exhausted all your attempts to get a correct string format for your datetime, you automatically `raise ValueError('no valid date format)`. Instead, you can either return the string unchanged, or you could return a default date string.

For the latter:

```
def try_parsing_date(text):
    for fmt in ('%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', '%Y/%m/%d', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'):
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(text, fmt).strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return '1900/01/01'
```

Alternatively, a function that does not `return` anything will automatically return `None` to the caller, so you could simply have:

```
def try_parsing_date(text):
    for fmt in ('%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', '%Y/%m/%d', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'):
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(text, fmt).strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

And then handle it outside of the function with:

```
if not try_parsing_date(some_string): # OR if try_parsing_date(some_string) is None:
    # Do something here
```

Comment: @EdwardMordechay You're welcome. If you feel this answered your question, I'd be grateful if you could [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). I notice that you haven't done that for any of your questions, and it means they are all technically "unsolved" and you also get reputation for accepting.